# Searching a hashtable and moving duplicates

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I have a script used to calculate game matchups for softball (really any sport). The script uses a round robin style calculation to create the matchups so that each team gets to play each other team at least once. This particular script allows you to enter the number of Teams and the number of Games. Based on the number of games you may have teams playing each other 2 or 3 times. So I also have the script reverse the matchups to simulate Home vs Away so no team has an advantage on home field if playing more than once.

My problem comes in when the final output is displayed. I didn't realize that for each "game" (series of matchups of all teams) some teams are listed twice in the same game/week. We don't want any team to play twice in the same week/game. 
In the script I take an array of matchups and convert them to a hashtable where it groups the matchups to the number of teams/2.

How can I rearrange the hashtable values where there are duplicate values and swap them with another "Game" to create games where no team plays twice (see below)?

```html
# Show input box popup and return the value entered by the user. 
function Read-InputBoxDialog([string]$Message, [string]$WindowTitle, [string]$DefaultText) 
{
     Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
     return [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($Message, $WindowTitle, $DefaultText) 
}

#define numbers of teams and games maybe use fields later

$teams = Read-InputBoxDialog -Message "Number of teams:" -WindowTitle "Teams" -DefaultText "3"
if ($teams -eq "0") { Write-Host "You clicked Cancel" } 
elseif ([int]$teams -gt "2" -and [int]$teams -lt 13) { Write-Host -foreground yellow "$teams Teams" } 
else { Write-Host "You entered $teams which is higher than the 12 teams this was designed for" }


$fields = Read-InputBoxDialog -Message "Number of fields:" -WindowTitle "Teams" -DefaultText "2"
if ($fields -eq $null) { Write-Host "You clicked Cancel" } 
elseif ([int]$fields -gt "0" -and [int]$fields -lt "4") { Write-Host -foreground green "$fields Fields" }  
else { Write-Host "You entered $fields which is higher than the 3 fields this was designed for" }

$gamess= "0"
$allplay= [int]$teams-1
$gamess = Read-InputBoxDialog -Message "Number of Games:" -WindowTitle "Games" -DefaultText "12"
if ($gamess -eq 0) { Write-Host "No value specified" } 
elseif ([int]$gamess -lt $allplay) {Write-host -foreground red "You must have more than 2 minus the number of teams or there won't be enough matches" }
elseif ([int]$gamess -lt "34") { Write-Host -foreground cyan "$gamess Games" } 
else { Write-Host "You entered $gamess which is more than 3 times the number of teams" }

#build array of teams
$a= 1..$teams

#if teams is odd number add a bye team to symbolize a bye for the opponent, thus making the number of teams even again
if ($teams % 2 -eq 1){$a += "bye"}
$parts = $a.length/2

#functions for game and rotating arrays borrowed most of the code for this from: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/2008WindowScriptingGamesAdvancedPowerShellEvent7.aspx 
[array]$global:games = $nul
function rotateArray($a)
{
 $first, $rest = $a
 $a = $rest + $first
 return $a
}
#function for creating away matchups 1 at a time
function makeGamesA($a)
{
 $i = 0;
 while($i -lt $a.Length/2)
 {
  $global:games = $global:games + ($a[$i].ToString() + " v " + $a[$a.Length-1-$i].ToString())
  $i++
 }  
}
#function for creating home matchups one at a time
function makeGamesH($a)
{
 $i = 0;
 while($i -lt $a.Length/2)
 {
  $global:games = $global:games + ($a[$a.Length-1-$i].ToString() + " v " + $a[$i].ToString())
  $i++
 }  
}
#here we create X as the variable that decides whether this is an away or home game and run the matching function based on even or odd value.
$x = 1
$z = 0
while($z -lt $gamess)
{
 if ($z -eq [int]$x*($a.length-1)) {$x++}
 if ($x % 2 -eq 1) {makeGamesA($a)}
 else {makeGamesH($a)}
 # hold on to the first one
 
 $first, $rest = $a
 #rotate the rest
 $rest = rotateArray($rest)
 $a = [array]$first + $rest
 $z++
}
#Collect into long array of match ups
$a = [collections.arraylist]$global:games
#convert values into hash table for each game played 
$b = @{}
$count = 1
$a |% {$b[$count % $gamess] += @($_);$count++}
$b= $b.getEnumerator() | sort-object Name

# Setting formatting specifications for each column in a hash table:
$column1 = @{expression="Name"; width=10; `
label="Game"; alignment="left"}
$column2 = @{expression="Value"; width=40; `
label="Team Matchups: Home vs. Away"; alignment="right"}
$f= $b | Format-table $column1, $column2
#print it out on the screen.
$f
read-host -foreground cyan "press any key to when finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you mean a duplicate matchup would be team 1 vs. team 2 and team 2 vs team 1, is that right? If so, imagine the following "matchup grid". Consider the first row, team one doesn't get matched up with itself, but it does the rest. On row 2, team 2 doesn't get matched up with team 1 again (duplicate) or itself, but it does the rest, and so on and so on.

```
 |1|2|3|4|5|6
-+-+-+-+-+-+-
1|n|y|y|y|y|y
-+-+-+-+-+-+-
2|n|n|y|y|y|y
-+-+-+-+-+-+-
3|n|n|n|y|y|y
-+-+-+-+-+-+-
4|n|n|n|n|y|y
-+-+-+-+-+-+-
5|n|n|n|n|n|y
-+-+-+-+-+-+-
6|n|n|n|n|n|n
```

This code will generate the grid assuming there are 6 team. It's just going through numbers for now, but you could just as easily iterate through a list of team instead of the numbers. And since you're already taking steps to ensure you have an even number of team, then you're all set!

```
for($i=0; $i -lt 6; $i++){
    [string]$str = ""
    for($j=0; $j -lt 6; $j++){
        if($i -ge $j){ $str = "$str n" }
        else{ $str = "$str y" }
    }
    Write-Output "$str `n"
}
```

To further refine into a list of team vs. team, here's an example.

```
$teams = @("Packers","Raiders","Patriots","Seahawks","Browns","Cowboys")

for($i=0; $i -lt $teams.Count; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j -lt $teams.Count; $j++){
        if($i -lt $j){
            Write-Output "$($teams[$i]) vs. $($teams[$j])"
        }
    }
}

Packers vs. Raiders
Packers vs. Patriots
Packers vs. Seahawks
Packers vs. Browns
Packers vs. Cowboys
Raiders vs. Patriots
Raiders vs. Seahawks
Raiders vs. Browns
Raiders vs. Cowboys
Patriots vs. Seahawks
Patriots vs. Browns
Patriots vs. Cowboys
Seahawks vs. Browns
Seahawks vs. Cowboys
Browns vs. Cowboys
```

Comment: Not exactly. By duplicates I mean any instance of a team that shows up twice in one game:
Example output of the current script
Game 1: [1 v 2, 3 v 4, 1 v 5]

You'll notice for game one that team 1 plays twice in the same Game series in our case each Game is a week so team 1 would play twice that week. 
Also in the current script I purposely invert the team assignments to create an "away vs home" scheme. So 1v2 and 2v1 are actually the same game just played on different locations.

Answer (score 0):

I did some thinking and drew the match ups out on paper and couldn't figure out why I would never get a single instance of a team showing up twice in a game series. then I realized my conversion from the original Array to the hashtable was causing the matchups to get ordered differently thus causing the duplicates (for clarification see my comment to campbells answer). I decided to change it up and have it convert the array into another array grouping the matchups using # of teams divided by 2.

```html
function Split-Collection {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $Collection,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateRange(1, 247483647)][int] $Count
        )
        begin {
            $Ctr = 0
            $Arrays = @()
            $TempArray = @()
        }
        process {
            if (++$Ctr -eq $Count) {
                $Ctr = 0
                $Arrays += , @($TempArray + $_)
                $TempArray = @()
                return
            }        
            $TempArray += $_ 
        }
        end {
        if ($TempArray) { $Arrays += , $TempArray }
        $Arrays
      }
    }

    #split up the array output the values to the form variable.

    $b = $a | Split-collection -Count $parts | %{ $_ -join ' | '}
```

My output now looks something like this: which was the desired affect. Each game is a representation of all matchups that can play simultaneously.

Game  20 :  1 v 4 | 5 v 3 | bye v 2

Game  21 :  1 v 5 | bye v 4 | 2 v 3

Game  22 :  bye v 1 | 5 v 2 | 4 v 3

Game  23 :  2 v 1 | bye v 3 | 5 v 4

Game  24 :  3 v 1 | 2 v 4 | bye v 5